# Something different than this.node.nextnode.nextnode?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

just a quick question. I am using .NextNode.NextNode to go to the next node:

```
var itemNode = doc.XPathSelectElement("/Channel/item/g:id[text()=" +stuff.ID+"]", namespaceManager);
var priceNode = (XElement)itemNode.NextNode.NextNode;
```

Is there a way do this like passing in an index? :

```
var priceNode = (XElement)itemNode[2]
```

Comment: Just a guess but maybe `var priceNode = (XElement)itemNode.NodesAfterSelf().ToList()[2];`

Comment: @user603007 It work's but has definitely worse performance ...